# how to create horizontal line in same row with li last-child

Tags: html, css, line

want to ask how can I create line with css as the picture below?
[image]
The line keep going under the menu, but not next to the 04.
Please help me. Thank you.
https://codepen.io/rae0724/pen/xWMRgd

```
<div class="menu-wrapper">
  <ul class="menu">
    <li><a href="#1">1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#2">2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#3">3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#4">4</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

.menu-wrapper {
    position:fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: auto;
    z-index: 9;
    width: 100%;
}
.menu{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 0 0 20px;
}
.menu li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 10px;
}
.menu li a{
    text-decoration:none;
    color: blue;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
.menu-wrapper {
 position:fixed;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 height: auto;
 z-index: 9;
 width: 100%;
}
.menu{
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0 0 0 20px;
}
.menu li {
 display: inline-block;
 margin: 10px;
}
.menu li a{
 text-decoration:none;
 color: blue;
 padding: 6px 12px;
 display: block;
}
.menu:after {
   content: " ";
    width: 150px;
    height: 2px;
    background: red;
    position: absolute;
    top: 25px;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu-wrapper">
  <ul class="menu">
    <li><a href="#1">1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#2">2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#3">3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#4">4</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: this should be the best way to create the line, thanks ^^

Answer (score 2):

Try to make use of `:last-child` here to target last child and use `:after` pseudo class to make line with `position:absolute`.(Remember to set `position:relative` tp parent `a`)

```css
.menu-wrapper {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: auto;
  z-index: 9;
  width: 100%;
}

.menu {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 0 0 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.menu li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 10px;
}

.menu li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: blue;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}

.menu li:last-child a:after {
  content: "";
  width: 1000px;
  height: 2px;
  background: red;
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
  top: 13px;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu-wrapper">
  <ul class="menu">
    <li><a href="#1">1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#2">2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#3">3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#4">4</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: hi, thanks for the answer, but i want the line to become width 100% which fill up the parent div's width. With this way, it can't reach 100% width.

Comment: @demoncoder here is the trick...try to increase width of line and put `overflow:hidden` to the parent

Answer (score 0):

```
.menu-wrapper {
    position:fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: auto;
    z-index: 9;
    width: 100%;
}
.menu{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 0 0 20px;
}
.menu li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 10px;
}
.menu li a{
    text-decoration:none;
    color: blue;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    display: block;
}
.menu li a:last-child:after {
    content: "";
    height: 2px;
    background: #000;
    width: 100px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 25%;
    top: 24px;
}

<div class="menu-wrapper">
  <ul class="menu">
    <li><a href="#1">1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#2">2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#3">3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#4">4</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="menu-wrapper">
  <ul class="menu">
    <li><a href="#1">1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#2">2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#3">3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#4">4</a></li>
    <li id="line"><a ></a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

in css

```
.menu-wrapper {
    position:fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: auto;
    z-index: 9;
    width: 100%;
}
.menu{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 0 0 20px;
}
.menu li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 10px;
}
.menu li a{
    text-decoration:none;
    color: blue;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    display: block;
}
#line{

  width:150px;
  height:2px;
  position:absolute;
  top:10px;
  background-color:red;
}
```

here is the working fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/oyqa2yr8/5/

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this with `li:last-child::after{}`

```css
.menu-wrapper {
    position:fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: auto;
    z-index: 9;
    width: 100%;
}
.menu{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 0 0 20px;
}
.menu li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 10px;
}
.menu li a{
    text-decoration:none;
    color: blue;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    display: block;
}
li:last-child::after{
border-right:4px solid red;
border-right-width:300px;
height:2px;
content:"";
position:absolute;
right:16%;
top:23px;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu-wrapper">
  <ul class="menu">
    <li><a href="#1">1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#2">2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#3">3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#4">4</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```